# Android - can i use one sdk for any beacons?

Tags: android, sdk, ibeacon, estimote, android-ibeacon

i have some beacons one of them is the **estimote** beacon and other one is the **İBKS** beacon But i made an application for estimote its okay, but it didnt work for İBKS. So is it possible to make just one application but work for more beacons from different companys. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a single SDK provided it supports the format of all your beacons.  The [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library) allows you to configure multiple proprietary beacon formats with code like this:

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m-2-3=aabb,i-4-19,i-20-21,i-22-23,p-24-24,d-25-25"));
```

You simply have to do a Google search to find the format for your beacon types, then replace the string in the example above.

Of the two types you mention, both claim to be iBeacon compatible, so you need a SDK that allows configuring that format.  If you are having trouble detecting one of them, first try an off  the shelf beacon scanner like [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate), which is based on the library mentioned above.